# Calling a function only once from update in different situations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I already know how to call a function only once from `Update()`

```
void Update(){
    if(x == "blah" && once == true)
    {
        //call a function here
       once = false;
    }
}
```

But how can I do this multiple times?

I have a enemy (boss) and I want to call a method when his health level reaches 0.75, 0.5, 0.25 (but only once each time).

This is my code BTW:

```
//In the update method :

if (health <= StartHealth * 0.75)
{
    Escape();
}
// in the function being called :

else if(health<= StartHealth * 0.75f && health > StartHealth * 0.5f)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        GameObject x = Instantiate(clone, clonePointz[i].position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}

else if(health <= StartHealth * 0.5f && health > StartHealth * 0.25f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        GameObject x = Instantiate(clone, clonePointz[Random.Range(0, 2)].position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}

else if(health<= 0.25f * StartHealth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        GameObject x = Instantiate(clone, clonePointz[Random.Range(0, 2)].position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to spawn some additional enemies whenever the boss' health goes below some threshold? You could remember the last health value each Update and check that against your thresholds. Kind of making your once variable more granular than bool.

Comment: @Suigi yes thats exactly what i want to do :)  spawn some minions for the boss whenever it loses a quarter of it's health

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Unity at hand right now, but here's a little C# program that should do what you want it to and simulates the engine's `Update` calls.

It remembers the health value when `Update` was last called and only acts (i.e. spawns some minions) if the boss' health value has passed one of your thresholds between two `Update` calls.

```
void Main()
{
    var boss = new BossBehaviour();
    boss.Damage(0.1f);
    boss.Update();
    boss.Damage(0.3f);
    boss.Update();
    boss.Damage(0.15f);
    boss.Update();
    boss.Update();
    boss.Damage(0.4f);
    boss.Update();
}

class BossBehaviour {

    float _currentHealth = 1.0f;
    float _healthFromLastUpdate = 1.0f;

    public void Update(){
        Console.WriteLine("Updating. Current health: {0}", _currentHealth);

        if (WasThresholdPassed(0.75f)){
            SpawnMinions();
        }

        if (WasThresholdPassed(0.5f)) {
            SpawnMinions();
        }

        if (WasThresholdPassed(0.25f)) {
            SpawnMinions();
        }

        _healthFromLastUpdate = _currentHealth;
    }

    bool WasThresholdPassed(float threshold) {
        if (_healthFromLastUpdate < threshold) 
            return false;
        if (_currentHealth < threshold)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    void SpawnMinions() {
        /* ... */
        Console.WriteLine("> Spawning minions. Current health: {0}", _currentHealth);
    }

    public void Damage(float percentDamage) {
        _currentHealth -= percentDamage;
    }

}
```

This is its output:

```
Updating. Current health: 0,9
Updating. Current health: 0,6
> Spawning minions. Current health: 0,6
Updating. Current health: 0,45
> Spawning minions. Current health: 0,45
Updating. Current health: 0,45
Updating. Current health: 0,04999995
> Spawning minions. Current health: 0,04999995
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it multiple times and know how many times, why not just use a simple counter variable?

```
//Have counter initialized to some pre-defined start value
void Update()
{
    if(x == "blah" && counter > 0)
    {
        //call a function here
        counter--;
    }
}
```

If I'm misunderstanding something, let me know and I'd be happy to try readjusting my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want to do it in different cases not just 3 times in a row. when enemy's health reachs 0.75, 0.5 and 0.25 of the starting amount of health

Comment: @babak-1990, that's why I left the inside of the function open. That way you get to do the fun part ;)